# 360 video stabilizer

Tags: video, vr

Can anybody recommend a free SW to stabilize 360 videos? 360-stabilizing algorithm is completely different than flat-video stabilizing.

This one is opensource, but is only for flat videos:

https://github.com/gyroflow/gyroflow

Maybe its output can be fed to another program to stabilize the 360 video?